# Android get Position of Bitmap in ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am using [CropView](https://github.com/lyft/scissors) which extends an Android `ImageView`.  It allows the image with in the the view to be scaled and moved around. there does not appear to be any public reference to the image position or scale. Is there a way to get the position of an image relative to a regular ImageView that I can try.

I have also tried setting a touch listener on the CropView that simply prints the x & y positions of the touch but i don see how i can use these to move get the updated position of the image.

```
mCropView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "///" + event.getX() +  " __ " + event.getY());
        return false;
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/lyft/scissors/blob/master/scissors/src/main/java/com/lyft/android/scissors/CropView.java

The CropView itself is the viewport. Cropview has two methods getViewportWidth
and getViewportHeight. You'll need them.

The image that is scaled, moved, cropped etc is a Drawable. Drawable has a getBounds method that will return a Rect. You can get the top, left width and height from this Rect but you need to get the Drawable first.

CropView calls this Drawable "bitmap". You can get it calling the CropView's  getImageBitmap() method.

Once you have it, call getBounds which gives you the image's Rect.

To get the x and y you want you'll have to do a bit of math with the Rect's top, left, width and height along with the viewport's height and width which you'll get from CropView's getViewportHeight and getViewportWidth methods.

Simply:

```
vpwidth=cropview.getViewPortWidth();
vpheight=cropview.getViewPortHeight();
imagetop=cropview.getImageBitmap().getBounds().top;
imageleft=cropview.getImageBitmap().getBounds().left;
imageheight=cropview.getImageBitmap().getBounds().height;
imagewidth=cropview.getImageBitmap().getBounds().width;
```

`>`*math here*

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the method below,

```
    final float[] getPointOfTouchedCordinate(ImageView view, MotionEvent e) {

        final int index = e.getActionIndex();
        final float[] coords = new float[] { e.getX(index), e.getY(index) };
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        view.getImageMatrix().invert(m);
        m.postTranslate(view.getScrollX(), view.getScrollY());
        m.mapPoints(coords);
        return coords;

}
```

you can get the value

```
mCropView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float[] points = getPointOfTouchedCordinate(v, event);
        Log.d(TAG, "///" + points[0] +  " __ " + points(1));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can You explain the fromView and toView Parameters? I am only moving the image within a single view (CropView). https://github.com/lyft/scissors/blob/master/art/demo.gif

Comment: Im little confused now. Are you trying to get the x, y position after zooming the pic ?

Comment: that and when it is moved around, the bitmap can be larger and a different shape to the view. Did you look at the demo gif?

Comment: i have added a drawing that (Hopefully) Clarifies what i am asking

Comment: try this and let me know.

Comment: Should `.invert(matrix);` be `.invert(m);`  ? or is `matrix` defined elsewhere?

Comment: it shud be .invert(m)

Comment: Unfortunately that is giving me the point of the touch and not the upper left corner of the image in relation to the view-able area

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to rely on pure xml and add to the Imagevie:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

this will lead to the desired output as drawn.

Comment: adding the image to the view is not my problem the problem is getting the co ordinates of the point shown in the circle in the upper left of the view-able area